# Setting Spring bean property value in ApplicationContext without using properties file

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I want to change the value of my bean property in my application context without reading from properties file. I will get property values set in the properties object. properties object will be passed to my api while calling api interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through a custom [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) and using a `PropertySource`
called [`PropertiesPropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertiesPropertySource.html)

Create a custom ApplicationContextInitializer this way:

```
public class PropertyRegisterAppInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MutablePropertySources sources = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("testkey", "testval");
        sources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("propertiesSource", props ));
    }

}
```

Register this `ApplicationContextInitializer` through `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>props.PropertyRegisterAppInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```